# resign app with ldid on iPhone6 but got the errors:"codesign_allocate: unknown flag: -A"

Tags: ios, codesign, entitlements

I'm using ldid to resign the app like: "ldid -Sent.xml app", but I got the error in iPhone6(iOS8):

```
codesign_allocate: unknown flag: -A
Usage: codesign_allocate -i input [-a <arch> <size>]... -o output
ldid.cpp(1031): _assert(WEXITSTATUS(status) == 0); errno=0
```

1.I can use "ldid -e app > ent.xml" to export the entitlements.

2.I can use both of them in iPhone5(iOS8).

Find that, the codesign_allocate is different:

（iPhone6）:
Usage: codesign_allocate -i input [-a  ]... -o output

（iPhone5）:
Usage: codesign_allocate -i input [-a  ]... [-A   ]... -o output

the iPhone6 one has no flag of -A